# You don't earn rep on upvotes but lose on unupvotes on CW posts?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, community-wiki, change-vote

I was surprised by this:

[image]

From "[How to delete an item in a list if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915920/how-to-delete-an-item-in-a-list-if-it-exists-python/4915964#4915964)".

Seems unfair if you don't earn rep for upvotes but lose on downvotes. It is even more unfair in it is an "unupvote".

Also if a moderator feels like removing the CW status from this question I would be thankful.

Comment: Keep in mind that an unupvote (undoing a previous upvote) is not the same as a downvote.

Comment: You should flag your answer to get it un-CW'd.

Answer (score 9):

That means the vote is unupvoted which was upvoted before your answer become community wiki. If the vote, for what you have not earned any reputation, is unupvoted you won't lose any reputation.

#### Update:

After looking at your reputation history, IMO this is the case:

Someone unupvoted for what you earned 10 rep in the past (i.e. when your answer was not CW) so you lose the points and then again upvoted so you didn't earn any reputation because is it CW post now.

Also to make your answer you can flag the answer and ask to remove CW status. But it all depends on moderators.

Comment: Looks like someone upvoted and took it back right away 3 hours ago.

Comment: @PauloScardine - See my edit.

Comment: I knew it was something fishy. :-) - someone unupvoted by accident, but they can't undo it upvoting again...

Comment: my vote goes for _"the vote is unupvoted which was upvoted"_ - I just like to vote